# Impoisble utilizar la propiedad filterField en p-column (PrimeNG)

Tags: angular4, primeng

Estoy intentando utilizar la propiedad `filterField` que se aplica al componente `p-column` dentro de `p-dataTable` del framework [PrimeNG](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/).

He intentado varias formas:

```
<p-column header="Categoria" field="id_categoria.nombre_categoria" [style]="{'width':'10%'}" sortable="true" filterField="id_categoria._id"></p-column>
```

De este modo, cuando hago debug en el método que filtra dentro del componente `dataTable`, no se le adhiere la propiedad al objeto.

```
<p-column header="Categoria" field="id_categoria.nombre_categoria" [style]="{'width':'10%'}" sortable="true" [filterField]="id_categoria._id"></p-column>
```

Y así, me tira una excepción porque el objeto que corresponde a la fila que se esta pintando se pierde.

Estoy utilizando la versión `5.2.0-rc.2` de primeng

¿Alguna idea? Gracias de antemano!

Comment: ¿Qué quiere decir el objeto se pierde?

Comment: Que objeto correspondiente a la fila que contiene la propiedad `id_categoria` no llega, ya que me salta una excepción, avisando de que no se puede obtener la propiedad `_id` de `undefined`

Comment: Has probado a poner solo el nombre del campo por el que quieres filtrar? Es decir: [filterField]="_id" o "'_id'"?

Comment: No me vale, si pusiera eso y funcionase, me pondría el _id del elemento de la fila, lo que yo necesito es el _id de una propiedad del elemento de la fila.